# AzDevops SelfHosted Agent spawn ENOENT Error when calling PythonScript Task

Tags: python, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, enoent

I hope you can help me, I've been looking for an answer but I couldn't find something concrete, thats why I'm creating this topic.

I'm having issues trying to execute a PythonScript from AzureDevops Pipelines, the script is supposed to validate the pom.xml version against the artifact in Azure Artifacts.. I have tested this locally in the same machine where the Agent is Running and is working, but whenever the pipeline runs, and try to execute my script from path option, it returns an ENOENT Error, I have enabled System.Debug option but I didn't see anything wrong, I also tested the same command on the host and It worked.. Also tried with different version of Python with any results..

This is the error I'm getting:

> [command]/usr/bin/python /home/azdevops/azagent/_work/2933/templates/azure-devops/anka/lib/helper-functions.py getPomVersion hpsais-izipay-webview/pom.xml

> ##[error]There was an error when attempting to execute the process '/usr/bin/python'. This may indicate the process failed to start.
> Error: spawn /usr/bin/python ENOENT

My host is:
Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

I also have this same task in a Release Pipeline but the difference is that this one is an inline script and is working properly.

Thanks in advance!